# Please help explain what this domain is doing (Program to add fibonacci sequence elements in array with a function)

Tags: c, arrays, function, sum, fibonacci

In class the TA was explaining that A[end+1] was better than A[end], but I forgot why. Can someone help explain if it is necessary because the program seems to work fine without it.
Also, if you would please help me with the return -1 for the ERROR trigger in the function.
Instead of printing the -1 value for the final sum in the event of an ERROR what specifically do I add and where to just print an ERROR message and not the -1?

```
/* Progrm.c

   Author:

   Adds fibonacci terms from start to end inclusive.

*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int start, int end);

int main() {

    int start, end, response;
 do {   
    printf("Enter start\n");
    scanf("%d",&start);
    printf("\nEnter end\n");
    scanf("%d",&end);
    printf("\n%d\n",f(start,end));
    printf("\nWould you like to solve additional problems ? \n"
    "Please enter 1 for yes or 0 for no: ");
    scanf("%d", &response);
    } while ( response == 1 );

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}

int f(int start, int end) {
    if(start<=0||end<=0||start>end) {
      fprintf( stderr, "\nError - Input data is invalid. Please enter "
      "start: > 0, end: > 0, \nand start < end.\n");                             
      return -1;
    }
    int A[end+1],i;                      /*Can you replace A[end+1] with just A[end]*/ 
    A[1]=1;                              /*and not encounter problems?*/
    A[2]=1;
    for(i=3;i<=end;i++)
       A[i]=A[i-1]+A[i-2];
    int sum=0;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
       sum+=A[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You need the `+1` because your are iterating `i` until it is equal to `end`, and `A[end]` requires `end+1` entries in the array (since the indices start at zero).  As for handling the error, `int result = f(start, end);` and then you can compare the result with `-1` and report the error, or report the final value if it OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops

```
for(i=3;i<=end;i++)
for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
```

both access `A[end]`. If you declare `int A[end]`, that is past the end of the array and you are writing to memory you shouldn't (probably `i`, but it's undefined behavior so all bets are off).  Declaring `int A[end-1]` means that writing to `A[end]` is valid.

Along the same lines, you should check that `end` is at least 3 at the beginning so you don't write to `A[2]` if the array is shorter than that.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question:

> Why A[end+1] was better than A[end] ?

This is because you are iterating till end and array index starts from 0. It means to accommodate values up to 'n', you have to take the size of array as 'n+1'. Say n = 5, size of array would be 5+1=6, 5 for indexes of 1 to 5 and one for 0.
Your second question:

> Can you replace A[end+1] with just A[end]?

So yes, we can do it by changing code in function f() as below:

```
    if(start<=0||end<=0||start>end) {  
       fprintf( stderr, "\nError - Input data is invalid. Please enter "
       "start: > 0, end: > 0, \nand start < end.\n");                             
       return -1;
    }

    start = start -1;  // decrease the value of start and end by 1
    end = end - 1;
    int A[end],i;  // A[end+1] changed to A[end]                     
    A[0]=1;    // decreased index by 1                          
    A[1]=1;    // decreased index by 1 
    for(i=2;i<end;i++)   // changed loop iteration from 2 till i<end
       A[i]=A[i-1]+A[i-2];
    int sum=0;
    for(i=start;i<end;i++)   // changed loop iteration till i<end
       sum+=A[i];
```

Your another question:

> Instead of printing the -1 value for the final sum in the event of an
>   ERROR what specifically do I add and where to just print an ERROR
>   message and not the -1?

To just print an ERROR message not -1, you have to change code in do-while loop as below:

```
// take one int variable and get the result in this
int result =  f(start,end);
// print the sum, only if there is no error
if(result!= -1)
    printf("\n%d\n",result );
```